# что за метод approve() в yii2?

Tags: yii2

Прошу ткнуть носом в документацию, ибо ничего не нашёл, кроме как тут https://yiiframework.com.ua/ru/doc/guide/test.unit/

```
// вызвать метод approve() и проверить, что комментарий утвержден
$comment->approve();
```

а из этого примера не понять, что оно там проверяет и зачем это надо

Answer (score 0):

Это просто метод написаный в классе Comment, который изменяет и сохраняет статус.

Там в начале статьи написано "Предположим, что мы хотим проверить класс модели Comment в демо-блоге." и если походить по ссылкам, то можно найти этот [класс](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/demos/blog/protected/models/Comment.php)

А сам метод выглядит вот так:

```
/**
 * Approves a comment.
 */
public function approve()
{
    $this->status=Comment::STATUS_APPROVED;
    $this->update(array('status'));
}
```

Т.е. это как раз тот метод, который мы тестируем. После его вызова у нас в базу должна произойти запись нового статуса `Comment::STATUS_APPROVED`.

Далее по коду мы сначала проверяем, поменялся ли действительно статус в текущем объекте:

```
$this->assertEquals(Comment::STATUS_APPROVED,$comment->status);
```

А потом проверям произошла запись в базу с помощью получения объекта из базы и ещё одной проверки:

```
$comment=Comment::model()->findByPk($comment->id);
$this->assertEquals(Comment::STATUS_APPROVED,$comment->status);
```

Comment: такого метода у себя в моделях я не нашёл, но есть такой:    
 public function isApprove()
    {
        return $this->status == self::STATUS_APPROVE or $this->status == self::STATUS_PAYMENT_IS_EXPECTED;
    }
я правильно понимаю, что вызов в контролере $model->approve() вызывает метод  isApprove() в модели?

Comment: Если вы не писали этого метода, то у вас его и не будет. Или вы запустили у себя `демо-блог`, на котором объясняется статья и не нашли метод `approve` там?

Comment: Я понял. Сейчас исправлю свой ответ, чтобы вам всё стало понятно.

Comment: не, вы не поняли) У меня в контроллере, который писал не я вызывается $model->approve(). Метода approve() в чистом виде у меня нигде нет, но есть isApprove(). Вот я и спрашиваю, может ли   $model->approve() вызывать метод isApprove() ?

Comment: В целом конечно такое возможно с помощью магического [метода _call](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call). Но в рамках статьи, которую вы рассматриваете тестируется конкретный метод approve(), который был написан ранее. Обещанные правки в ответ внёс. )